# Android Management API / Kiosk Mode: How to debug?

Tags: android-management-api

How can I debug an Android device that is set to `installtype: KIOSK` using the Android Management API? I have set `debuggingFeaturesAllowed` to `true` but `adb devices` does not even show the device when attached via USB cable. Is there a way to get a console output from such a device?

I'm currently using the following policy on the device:

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/LC0999999/policies/policy1",
  "version": "13",
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.package.name",
      "installType": "KIOSK",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
  ],
  "keyguardDisabled": true,
  "debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable USB debugging under developer settings?

Comment: I cannot go to settings when running in KIOSK mode.

Comment: `"debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true` only allows you to turn it on, it doesn't turn it on for you.

Comment: but where would I turn it on when in KIOSK mode? I obviously cannot got into the settings app.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to exit. You might want to try changing the policy to allow you to leave, change the setting, and then change the policy back to KIOSK.

Comment: But what if I want to debug the specifics of KIOSK mode? What if I have to debug the provisioning process of the Android Management API?

Comment: To get to settings whitelist the app:
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.settings",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    },

Answer (score 0):

*debuggingFeaturesAllowed* only allows the user to enable debugging features.  The user still needs to enable USB debugging through developer options.

The only way to enable USB debugging is through the Developer Options in Settings.  This would need to be done before applying the *installType: "KIOSK"* policy to the device.

Comment: That means that the whole provisioning process to get a device from zero to kioskmode installed app cannot be debugged then, right?

Comment: Technically you provision your device without KIOSK_MODE policy and apply it after you enable debug mode

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 2022, [debuggingFeaturesAllowed](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#Policy.FIELDS.debugging_features_allowed) has been deprecated !

> debuggingFeaturesAllowed
> (deprecated)
>
> debuggingFeaturesAllowed is deprecated. Please use
> advancedSecurityOverrides.developerSettings instead.
>
> Whether the user is allowed to enable debugging features.

To enable developer settings you need to patch your device with [AdvancedSecurityOverrides](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#AdvancedSecurityOverrides.FIELDS.developer_settings) maskfield with :

> {
> "developerSettings": enum ([DeveloperSettings](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#developersettings))
> }

DeveloperSettings can have 3 values :

- DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_UNSPECIFIED

> Unspecified. Defaults to DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_DISABLED.

- DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_DISABLED -

> Default. Disables all developer settings and prevents the user from
> accessing them.

- DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_ALLOWED

> Allows all developer settings. The  user can access and optionally
> configure the settings.